# Is it possible to execute an SSIS package remotely?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I want to execute an SSIS package stored on an SQL server (2008 R2) from another computer.  However, everything I've found online involves loading the package from the server and then running it locally.

Is it possible to run the package on the server?  Any resources are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To execute a package, you normally create a new job and use a job step to start the desired package.

1. If you got the sql server management studio(ssms) installed on your remote computer, you simply connect to the database engine and start the job. Alternativly, you can connect to the integration services with ssms and start the package directly.
2. If there is no ssms available, you can start the job using the stored procedure `sp_start_job`. You could use something like [this](http://sqlanalyzer.codeplex.com/) to execute.

Answer (score 1):

You could execute the stored procedure sp_start_job in the remote server. I've used it (creating a stored procedure to control a bit the parameterisation) succesfully.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186757.aspx